# Node js erro ao importar modulo

Tags: node.js, módulo-ecmascript, export

Boa tarde a todos, estou tentando organizar meu projeto, pra isso presciso trabalhar com o node, tenho uma função que cria um grafico, separei ela em um arquivo a parte e exportei esta função para que eu possa utilizar na minha view.
Porem ele da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo view.js

```
require('./modules/createGraphic')
```

Arquivo createGraphic

```
var createGraph =  function createGraph(matrix, title, classHtml) {
    var dimensao = []
    var measure = []
    dimensao = matrix.map((item) => { return item[0].qText })
    measure = matrix.map((item) => { return item[1].qText })

    var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName(classHtml)
    var chartGrap = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: dimensao,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'taxa',
          data: measure,
          borderWidth: 5,
          borderColor: ['rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)', 'rgba(192, 0, 0, 1)'],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', 'rgba(192, 0, 0, 0.2)'],
          pointBackgroundColor:'#800b0b',
          lineCap:'round'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: title
        }
      }
    })
  }
  module.exports = createGraph
```

As função esta funcionado. Fiz os teste e deu certo o que ta pegando é este arquivo.

Comment: Poderia postar o trecho de código que está utilizando esta referência? Você está utilizando esta função diretamente dentro de uma view?

Comment: require('./modules/createGraphic') 
require(["js/qlik"], function (qlik) {
  var app = qlik.openApp('Recurso Humanos.qvf', config);
  app.getObject('filtro', 'zSmqYhK')
  app.getObject('kpi1', 'dRApjU')
  app.getObject('aoLongo', 'ebnCpu')
  app.getObject('kpi2', 'HuKkTX')
  app.getObject('kpi3', 'eJKBPu')
  app.getObject('kpi4', 'gbwRegu')
  app.getObject('barraSelecao', 'CurrentSelections')})  este é o trecho do codigo q estaria na view, no momento nao quero mostrar nada na tela gostaria apenas de conseguir importas os modulos para executar essas funcoes de arquivos destintos.

Comment: ainda não está muito claro pra mim, mas sugiro migrar este trecho de código da view para um controller. Dentro do controller efetue o processamento necessário e então passe as informações (model) para view através do comando: `res.render('minhaView', { dados: 123 });`. Se ainda assim for necessário efetuar algum processamento dentro da view dê uma olhada neste link: https://medium.com/@marcelo.vismari/nodejs-express-ejs-como-usar-funcoes-durante-renderizacao-f51122e1eaca